# Compacting an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to write this if statement as compact as possible (to avoid having duplicate code)

```
if length == 10 if boolean is False or length == 13 if boolean is True:
```

The part that PyCharm does not like is the

```
if boolean is True
```

It asks for a colon.

PyCharm does not allow me to run it. Does anyone have a nice compact solution to this if?

Comment: I do not even know what this condition is trying to express. Maybe you're just looking for the `and` operator?

Comment: This seems like two questions. You should first be asking "what's wrong with my statement?" and only after you have determined that, you should ask "how do I make my now-working statement more compact?"

Comment: `if length == 13 if boolean else length == 10:`?

Comment: @deceze: I want to check if length equals 10, but only when the boolean value is false. Same for the second part, check if length equals 13 only when boolean is true. This allows me to save some duplicate code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It should only pass the if:if both length == 10 and boolean is false OR length == 13 and boolean is True

Comment: @MrKickkiller ...what? That does exactly what you just said you wanted it to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm sorry, i made a mistake. Your solution should work

Comment: @deceze: No I am not looking for and, far from that. I want to check if one condition applies when a certain value is met OR check if another condition applies when a seperate value is met.

Comment: @Kevin: Why can't I ask two questions in one post? I just asked for any suitable replacements for my broken code, that are as compact as possible. I asked for the compactness since otherwise the answer could have simply been to use nested if's which i do not want (needs duplicate code then)

Comment: Please do *not* use the is-operator to check for True or False! That is working is incidental. Instead, use a simple "if boolean" or "if not boolean". If you insist on doing a superfluous operation, do "if boolean == True". The is-operator is about object-identity, and there is no guarantee that True is True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (also known as a *"ternary"*) to write it out much more concisely:

```
if length == 13 if boolean else length == 10:
```

or, equivalently:

```
if length == (13 if boolean else 10):
```

Per the documentation:

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, *C* (*not x*); if *C* is true, *x* is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and its value is returned.

Comment: Oooh, I like the second version. The first one confuses me :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker well if we write code other people can understand it puts us out of a job!

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you meant

```
if (not boolean and length == 10) or (boolean and length == 13):
```

The parentheses aren't necessary, but I think they help readability. @jonsharpe's solution is even shorter and only has to evaluate `boolean` once, but it may be harder to read, especially if you're not familiar with Python's ternary expressions.

*Never*  use `is` for equality comparison (that's what `==` is for), but boolean types should never be explicitly compared to `True` or `False` anyway.